# SQL - Error: no such column - on joining tables

Tags: sql, join

The issue is as follows.
When I select 1st table, all columns exist. When I select 2nd table, all columns exist as well. But when I try to join them, the column on which I join never exists. I give up :( Any help please?

Table 1:

```
TABLE 'reviews' ('overall' integer NOT NULL, 'provider_id'  INTEGER NOT NULL  );
```

Table 2:

```
TABLE 'providers' ('id' integer NOT NULL, 'name'  text NOT NULL  );
```

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM reviews;
SELECT * FROM providers;
```

This shows an error: "Error: no such column: reviews.provider_id"

```
SELECT * FROM providers 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM reviews)
ON providers.id = reviews.provider_id;
```

Comment: You have a syntax error. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK. (Don't just give up. That asks us to do your basic debugging.) In a question, say what you expected to be OK & why, referencing authoritative documentation. For code questions give a [mre]. That includes DBMS. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need table aliases.  I would dispense with the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM providers p JOIN
     reviews r
     ON p.id = r.provider_id;
```

If you really want the subquery, you still need an alias:

```
SELECT *
FROM providers p JOIN
     (SELECT * FROM reviews) r
     ON p.id = r.provider_id;
```

But there is no need for a subquery and it is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks. I am selecting specific filds in the actual code. Thats why the subquery. Also I have it as a db.execute under python in flask. I believe a subquery is more optimal than building 2 lists from db in python and then merging them in python. But I may be wrong :-) Will try the solution and come back when done.

Comment: @ketazs . . . You can select the specific fields in the `select`.  No subquery is needed.

Comment: Thanks. I Have completely reworked thanks to you: SELECT p.id, r.provider_id FROM providers p, reviews r, WHERE p.id=r.providers_id; This merged tables as required :-)